# Alternative to For Each loop when setting properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, foreach

I'm struggling with some performance issues in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have a list where I need to set a couple properties. My code reads through the list via a for each loop and sets these two properties dependent on the records date value.

Here is the code:

```
//Build City Taxes List
var cityTaxInformationList = (from citycigtax ct in db.citycigtaxes
                                join statecigtax st in db.statecigtaxes on ct.stateid equals st.stateid
                                join transaction tr in db.transactions on ct.masterkey equals tr.masterkey
                                select new CityViewModel
                                {
                                    CityMasterKey = ct.masterkey,
                                    StateShortName = st.stateshortname,
                                    CityName = ct.cityname,
                                    TransactionStickTax = tr.sticktax,
                                    TransactionDateStamp = tr.datestamp,
                                    TransactionEffectiveDate = tr.effdate,
                                    TransactionKey = tr.transactionkey,
                                    IsHighestDate = false,
                                    SecondCityRates = null,
                                    RateCount = 0
                                }).ToList();

var topCityTaxes = cityTaxInformationList.GroupBy(x => x.CityMasterKey, (Key, grp) => grp.OrderByDescending(y => y.TransactionEffectiveDate).First()).ToList();

foreach (var tx in cityTaxInformationList)
{
    tx.IsHighestDate = topCityTaxes.Exists(x => x.TransactionEffectiveDate == tx.TransactionEffectiveDate && x.CityMasterKey == tx.CityMasterKey);
    if (tx.IsHighestDate == true)
    {
        tx.RateCount = cityTaxInformationList.Where(x => x.IsHighestDate == false && tx.CityMasterKey == x.CityMasterKey).Select(x => x.TransactionStickTax).Count();
        tx.SecondCityRates = string.Join(", ", cityTaxInformationList.Where(x => x.IsHighestDate == false && tx.CityMasterKey == x.CityMasterKey)
            .Select(x => String.Format("{0:0.00000}", x.TransactionStickTax + " " + "(" + String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", x.TransactionEffectiveDate) + ')')));

        if (tx.SecondCityRates == "")
        {
            tx.SecondCityRates = "None";
        }
    }
}

var TopCityTaxInformationList = cityTaxInformationList.GroupBy(x => x.CityMasterKey, (Key, grp) => grp.OrderByDescending(y => y.TransactionEffectiveDate).First()).ToList();

return TopCityTaxInformationList;
```

Is there a more efficient way of performing this? I'm looking at a list of 80,000 records and looping through each and every one is crushing performance.

Comment: Can you move any of the logic in to the initial query before the first `ToList()`? The [`let` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) might be of use in doing that.

Comment: what if you were to run / convert the query into SQL using LinqPad or something and run it on a sql server.. would you get the same performance hit..?

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop is not crushing your performance, the lookup using `topCityTaxes` is.  It's looking through the entire list in order to find a value (3 times!!).  Switch `topCityTaxes` to a dictionary, keyed by `CityMasterKey` and do a lookup.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I've never used a dictionary data type before. Are we talking about my tx.Exist statement? I should convert the topCityTaxes list to a dictionary and then run the exist logic on it?

Comment: Yes.  Use `ToDictionary`.  Then you can look up possible values by `dict[tx.CityMasterKey]`.  The `topCityTaxes.Exists` is worst-case looking through all values.  The two `Where` clauses are by definition looking through all values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `foreach` loop, but what's **inside** that loop - a lot of ineffective LINQ queries against the whole list.

Looking at what you are doing inside and what you are returning from the function, you don't even need a lookup structure as suggested by @Kyle W, all you need is a **proper processing algorithm**.

Here is IMO the equivalent of what you are doing

```
//Build City Taxes List
var cityTaxInformationList = ...;
// Build and return Top City Tax Information List
var topCityTaxInformationList = cityTaxInformationList.GroupBy(x => x.CityMasterKey, (key, elements) =>
{
    var elementList = elements.OrderByDescending(e => e.TransactionEffectiveDate).ToList();
    var first = elementList[0];
    first.IsHighestDate = true;
    first.RateCount = elementList.Count - 1;
    first.SecondCityRates = first.RateCount == 0 ? "None" : string.Join(", ",
         elementList.Skip(1).Select(x => string.Format("{0:0.00000} ({1:M/d/yyyy})",
             x.TransactionStickTax, x.TransactionEffectiveDate)));
    return first;
}).ToList();

return topCityTaxInformationList;
```

The rationale is that all the logic in the original code is for the elements sharing the same `CityMasterKey`, and `GroupBy` perfectly does that separation for you.

Comment: Wow this crushes the way I was doing it initially. My problem was my redundancies within the loop? Thank you very much, Kyle and Ivan!

Comment: Your problem was the `topCityTaxes.Exists(...` and the 2 `cityTaxInformationList.Where(...)` inside the loop. You probably know that these methods are like foreach-ing the **whole** list and evaluating the criteria. From a curiosity, please put me a note what's the difference in performance between the original and the proposed (of course if you decide to give it a try).

Comment: Initially, processing time was upwards of 5 minutes. Now it spans from 3-5 seconds.